# React Native Android keyboard highlight text issue

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Having an android issue when highlighting text in an input component on React Native.

Functions fine when restarting application, you can open and close the input box and type and send messages as follows:

[image: Normal messaging view]

[image: Adding and sending text, text input in correct location]

Now, the problem occurs when you hold onto the text to highlight it (so you can copy/paste/cut text):

[image: Highlighted functionality shown at top which then breaks app view state functionality]

After this has happened then closing and reopening the text box has the same effect (the bottom bar navigation is showing). The keyboard now appears to be overlaid on top of the screen as the text below is being rendered as if the keyboard is minimised regardless of whether it is active or not.

How does this aspect break state across the application for the keyboard? Could someone link or inform me of how to deal with or have access to the copy/paste functionality that appears at the top for Android? What doesn't make sense is that the whole application becomes broken for keyboard input once this has happened - you can make it work again by restarting the application.

The relevant code is below (if there's something missing just say):

DeviceEventEmitter code:

```
  componentDidMount: function(){
    let context = this,

    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardWillShow', function(e: Event) {
        context.setState({
            height: context.listViewMaxHeight - e.endCoordinates.height + 50,
        });
    });

    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardWillHide', function(e: Event) {
        context.setState({
            height: context.listViewMaxHeight,
        })
    });
}
```

TextInput component in the component render function:

```
      <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            maxNumberOfLines={8}
            multiline={true}
            autoFocus={false}
            editable={true}
            numberOfLines= {5}
            ref='textInput'

            onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
            style={[styles.textInput, {height: context.props.textInputHeight}]}
            placeholder={context.props.placeholder}
            placeholderTextColor="#5A5A5A"
            value={context.state.text}/>

            <Button
                style={styles.sendButton}
                onPress={this._onPress}
                disabled={this.state.disabled}>
            Send </Button>
      </View>
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the problem seeing as the keyboard behaves correctly most of the time, but I don't think keyboardWillHide and keyboardWillShow is implemented yet for Android. However, keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide is. See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3468

Comment: @pinewood Yeh the keyboard works fine, as when the highlighted functionality appear at the top you can still type and close the keyboard, so the keyboard isn't the issue. What the highlighted text breaks though is the height of the view where the contents go back to where it would be if the keyboard isn't showing regardless of the keyboard event emitter setState height. If there's a component name for it I may be able to manage the state  better based on its properties and if it's active

Comment: @pinewood oh and yeh I tried using DidShow and DidHide ofcourse, both function the same.

Answer (score 0):

The main first part fix to this problem was using keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide instead of keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide. (thank you @pinewood)

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardDidShow', function(e: Event) {
    context.setState({
        height: context.listViewMaxHeight - e.endCoordinates.height + 50,
    });
});

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardDidHide', function(e: Event) {
    context.setState({
        height: context.listViewMaxHeight,
    })
});
```

The second component is making sure to play around with the manifest to get the desired keyboard functionality, currently we changed to:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan" />
```

The issue with the keyboard is also better detailed here - https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-tab-navigator/issues/48